# Need some help regarding Android Studio emulator and device issues

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I was just wondering if you could help me with some Android Studio issues.. I am not able to run any emulators or debuggable devices on Android Studio.. It shows the error..

```
/dev/kvm not found. Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.
```

Though I have enabled the `VT-x` from BIOS settings.. Also, while installing INtel HAXM.. the setup ends prematurely.. though it shows installed afterwards

But while installing it ends prematurely stating the error

```
Failed to configure the driver
```

It would be great if you could just help me up with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

First try your Android mobile with USB dubbing enable. And run your application. Or try to reinstall Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an intel machine you need to launch into BIOS and then under advanced there should be an option to enable VT-x. Another thing you can try is to use the genymotion emulator. It is much smoother than the one that comes with android studio. Just give it a google, it is very easy to setup and has a plugin in android studio.

Hope this helps!